# How to add class for h4 tag which is in second li - jquery

Tags: jquery

**EDIT**: Added UL class

```
    <ul class="expand-coll-list">
    <li>
    <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-expand">
    <span class="exp-coll"></span>Bookmarks</h4>
    <div class="item-list">
    <ul>      
    <li class="first"><div>first Asset</div></li>
    <li><div>Latest Updates</div></li>
    <li><div>asset image</div></li>
    <li><div>test Asset 1</div></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>

    <li>
    <h4 class="title-exp-coll title-expand">
    <span class="exp-coll"></span>Menu</h4>
    <p>No menu.</p>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

For example if i load content/page1

I need to **remove class titl-expand and add class title-collapse** in the **h4 tag** which is in **first li**

For example if i load content/page2

I need to do the same function for page1 in the h4 tag which is in **second li**

My Code:

Which works for first case but not for second...

```
if(arg[1] == 'content' && arg[2] == 'page1') {
     $(".expand-coll-list li:first").children("h4").removeClass("title-collapse").addClass("title-expand");
} else if(arg[1] == 'content' && arg[2] == 'page2') {
     $(".expand-coll-list li:eq(1)").children("h4").removeClass("title-collapse").addClass("title-expand");
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I dont see you putting in .expand-coll-list anywhere in your html? is that all of your html?

Comment: @@Benny: please see now. added ul class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the css3 selector :nth-child(), that should help you in your problem!
$('.expand-coll-list li:nth-child(indexOfLiGoesHere)').addClass('classToBeAdded');

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to remove a class that doesn't currently exist on the h4's (title-collapse) and add a class they already have (title-expand). Without even checking if your selectors are correct, it doesn't appear this code would do anything.